# Who is an adjuster?

Tags: meaning, terminology, word-usage

> Then Hartstein, the adjuster for the insured, and Lazard, the adjuster
>   for the company, both of whom had had more or less to do with her in
>   connection with settling up for other fires, recognised her.

It's a phrase from a story, written in 1912 year. In the dictionary said that an adjuster is someone whose job is to get information about an accident, theft, etc. in order to decide how much money to pay an insurance customer.
 In  the sentence there are two kinds of adjusters, could anyone try to explain the duties of both of them, please.

Comment: They're usually called [***loss** adjusters*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loss-adjuster) (a sufficiently common collocation that it gets its own entry in the dictionary).

Comment: Thank you for telling me this definition!

Comment: In a nutshell, the adjuster for the insured attempts to get as much for the insured as possible, the adjuster for the insurance company tries to minimize the payout.

Comment: When asking questions about the meaning of terms from stories, you might consider trying [literature.se] Stack Exchange instead. This site (English SE) is more focused on the study of advanced linguistics, so they can help you with the meaning, usage, and etymology of words. But Literature SE is focused on the study of language *in context*, so they can explain how and why the words are used in that story and what they might suggest there. (Also, English SE is quick to close questions that aren't considered to be "expert level", Literature SE much less so.)

Comment: Thank you for your correction, I didnt know about Literature Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a definition of insurance adjuster:

> An insurance adjuster is someone who investigates claims to determine how much (or if) your insurance company should pay you for damages/losses to your stuff or place.

[Source](https://www.lemonade.com/insuropedia/dictionary/insurance-adjuster/)

In general, the implied duty of the adjuster for the insured (Hartstein) would be to get as much money as possible for the claim; the implied duty of the adjuster for the company (Lazard) would be to grant as little as possible.

In practice, these two parties would attempt to come to an equitable agreement, or if unable, would go to court.

Comment: Would you call an adjuster for the insured "a lawyer" of a company nowadays?

Comment: I would not. The adjuster works with the lawyers in his or her insurance, but seldom has a J.D.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. So as i understand Hartstein is hired by the insured company, and Lazart is an employee of insurance company? Tell me please am I right?

Comment: Probably two different insurance companies. Company A represents "her," the insured. Hartstein works for Company A. Company B represents "the company." Lazard works for Company B. I can't tell much more from the snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your help